# No puedo ver el procedimiento almacenado en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: stored-procedure, visual-studio-2017

Hice un procedimiento almacenado en VS 2017 en el explorador de objetos, le di a Actualizar, actualicé las carpetas, pero no veo nada.

La base de datos está en Azure.

Si intento ejecutar el script de nuevo me sale el mensaje:

> El modelo ya tiene un elemento con el mismo nombre dbo.sp_ingresar_capacitacion

Cerré VS y lo abrí de nuevo, intenté corre el script y salió
El modo SQLCMD debe estar habilitado para ejecutar correctamente este script

Resulta que los queries en VS se hacen por otro lado Herramientas > Sql server > New query

Me sale ahora el error

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.Capacitaciones' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba malo el script, lo modifiqué y ahora funciona. Como se puede ver Descripción estaba dos veces y faltaba una parte luego de db.Capacitaciones

```
Create Procedure [dbo].sp_ingresar_capacitacion
    @Nombre nvarchar(50),
    @Descripcion nvarchar(50),
    @Horario nvarchar(50),  
    @Objetivo nvarchar(30),
    @Imagen nvarchar(50),
    @FechaInicio datetime,
    @FiechaFinal datetime,
    @Lugar nvarchar(30)

as
begin
insert into dbo.Capacitaciones
values (@Nombre, @Descripcion, @Horario, @Descripcion, @Objetivo, @Imagen, @FechaInicio, @FiechaFinal, @Lugar)
End
```